# String to date conversion with excess hours

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, casting, timestamp

Having the following example strings:

```
'2015-01-01 23:51:00 AD'
'2015-01-01 24:51:00 AD'
'2015-01-01 26:51:00 AD'
'2015-01-01 27:51:00 AD'
```

Is there any way (by running a SQL query) to change the hour? If higher than 24 to do a `hour - 24`

So the resulting rows are:

```
'2015-01-01 23:51:00 AD'
'2015-01-01 00:51:00 AD'
'2015-01-01 02:51:00 AD'
'2015-01-01 03:51:00 AD'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's not a `date`. It's a `timestamp`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html)

One way (of many):

```
SELECT overlay(string
               placing to_char(substring(string, 12, 2)::int % 24, '00')
               from 12 for 2);
```

Then you can just cast: `(expression)::timestamp` or use `to_timestamp()`.

[String functions in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)
[`%` is the modulo operator.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html)

Or possibly faster (discarding the era indicator `AD`):

```
SELECT left(string, 10)::date + substring(string, 12, 8)::interval::time
```

`interval` allows any number of hours. When casting back to `time` you get the adjusted 24h-time as desired. And you can simply add `date` and `time` to produce a `timestamp` in Postgres.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9eecb/113)